# Android GPS destination

Tags: java, android, gps

I have made an android app that gets GPS coordinates in an SMS and saves it.I know my current GPS location.Now I want my app to tell me in terms of North,South,East,West to reach destination gps coordinates.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The location class has a bearing to method that returns the degrees to a location.  O is north.  180 south etc.

```
float bearing = locationa.bearingTo(locationb);
```

check out the sample code 
https://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html